# Laravel validator - connects to database

Tags: php, validation, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have a database limitation in Laravel's validation rules:

```
$rules = [
    'customer_id' => 'required|id|unique:customers|min:1',
];

// (...)

$validator = Validator::make($dataToSave, $rules);
```

On local machine, test passes and everything is allright. But on build server (Bamboo), where there is no database installed, the PHPUnit fails, because it cannot connect to database. When I remove `unique:customers` rule, test passes.

How can I refactor code, so the phpunit test will pass regardless of the environment?

Comment: Do you  use costomers table on your default database?

Comment: Yes, in database there is table `customers`. On local machine tests passes, but on build server where there isn't database at all, test fails. Shouldn't tests pass on each environment?

Comment: Without database how `unique:customers` validation pass?

Comment: Shouldn't the validator be somehow refactored/abstracted to another class, so I can mock validator behavoiur in PHPunit?

Answer (score 1):

Using [unique](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique) rule u MUST have DB connection. No variants.
It checks if the value unique among rows in database.

On local machine OK - because u have connection.
On remote NOT OK - because u have no connection.

Just install database and migrations on you Bamboo.
Otherwise removing `unique:customers|` will break your application logic.

BUT. if `customers`.`customer_id` is defined as unique key in database table, you CAN remove this `unique:customers|` and catch error when saving data (if not unique value passed)

Comment: Shouldn't the validator be somehow refactored/abstracted to another class, so I can mock validator behavoiur in PHPunit?

Comment: so.. here it is \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUnique